# How to find out if a model class is db or a ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I created a utility to exchange or zip all the entities for a kind. But how can I find out if the model_class used is a db.Model or an ndb.Model?

```
def _encode_entity(self, entity):                                             

    if self.ndb :
        entity_dict = entity.to_dict()                                                     
        self.entity_eid = entity.key.id()
        entity_dict['NDB'] = True
    else :
        entity_dict = db.to_dict(entity)
        self.entity_eid = entity.key().name()
        entity_dict['NDB'] = False

    ....
```

Now I use :

```
def queryKind(self):

    try :
        self.query = self.model_class.query()
        self.ndb = True
    except AttributeError :
        self.query = self.model_class.all()
        self.ndb = False
    return self.make(self._encode_entity)       # make a zip or a page
```

**UPDATE : The solution** I have used. See also Guido's answer

```
self.kind = 'Greeting'
module = __import__('models', globals(), locals(), [self.kind], -1)
self.model_class = getattr(module, self.kind)
entity = self.model_class()

if isinstance(entity, ndb.Model): 
    self.ndb = True
    self.query = self.model_class.query()
elif isinstance(entity, db.Model): 
    self.ndb = False
    self.query = self.model_class.all()
else :
    raise ValueError('Failed to classify entities of kind : ' + self.kind)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about import ndb and db, and testing for the entity being an instance of their respective Model classes?

```
if isinstance(entity, ndb.Model):
    # Do it the NDB way.
elif isinstance(entity, db.Model):
    # Do it the db way.
else:
    # Fail.  Not an entity.
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use an attribute that does exist only in `ndb` or the other way around.

for example `_has_repeated` or `_pre_get_hook` which are properties of the `ndb` entities.
so you could do:

```
self.ndb = hasattr(self, '_has_repeated')
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I already tried something like that, but I gave up to soon. Using _pre_get_hook made the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine. If I do not receive a better answer I will accept it. I am waiting because "_has_repeated" is not documented as a property.

Comment: i would go with guidos answer... don't know why i didn't think about that.

Comment: It is a documented answer. Thanks for your help.