# repeated StructuredProperty of ndb.GeoPt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do I repeat geo points as structured properties?

My code looks like this:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
    segments = ndb.StructuredProperty(ndb.GeoPt, repeated=True)
```

When I try to run the code and create instances of MyModel I get the following error:

`AttributeError: type object 'GeoPt' has no attribute '_has_repeated'`

[How to find out if a model class is db or a ndb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241707/how-to-find-out-if-a-model-class-is-db-or-a-ndb) seems to suggest that _has_repeated is a property specific to ndb models, and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured
 seems to suggest that ndb.GeoPt is identical to db.GeoPt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use GeoPt with structured property? Just use something like this:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  segments = ndb.GeoPtProperty(repeated=True)
```

But if you want to store extra information with each GeoPt object, then use structured property like this:

```
class GeoPtWithStruct(ndb.Model):
  geo = ndb.GeoPtProperty()
  bla = ndb.StringProperty()

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  segments = ndb.StructuredProperty(GeoPtWithStruct, repeated=True)
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I was replacing a custom geo point model with GeoPt, and forgot to remove the StructuredProperty wrapper. Thanks!